# Total number of Play Store Views including the ones directed from Google Play App Search Results (not just from campaigns)

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

Google Analytics has "Google Play Referral Report" that helps us in getting the total number of views of our app description page on Google play App. But it counts only those views that are directed from any campaign or source.
If I **search my app on Google Play App** and open its description page and install the app, that data is not shown in the "Google Play Referral Report".
Is there a way I can get the absolute total number of App description Page Views of my app including all the referrer page views, direct search on google play app or direct url open without any campaign.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much time on reports like that ... which basically tell you how many New Yorkers are walking down Park Avenue and who briefly look inside your shop window.  The *actual* problem, for any and every hopeful vendor of "an app," is that there are millions of apps out there, and they are mostly all the same.  People probably do *not* "find your app" by searching for it in Google's nor any other's App Store:  they discover it by other means, especially by satisfied players talking among themselves, or satisfied players of your previous games who want something new.

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Ya I agree to that, but the app I am working on is quite popular on other platforms and will be hitting android play store soon. I am sure there would be many users directly searching for it on the play store (for an instance, when I heard that clash of clans is released on android, I searched for it on play store and installed, I am sure many others would have done that too). So I feel its important data for already popular apps.

Comment: @AnkitKumarVats have you found an answer to this problem? I feel the same.